# Unity Custom Editor: Making a custom selection box with DrawRect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I call the following during OnSceneGui in my custom editor to draw a custom selection box. Everything works as it should, as far as the debugger tells me - the proportions and position of the rectangle are correct, and are adjusted as you'd expect when the mouse moves, but the rectangle will not draw. What am I getting wrong?

```
 Rect boundingRect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
 
     void CheckForBoundingBox()
         {
             Event e = Event.current;
             HandleUtility.AddDefaultControl( GUIUtility.GetControlID( FocusType.Passive ) );
     
             if( e.button == 0 )
             {
                 if( boundingRect.min != Vector2.zero )
                 {
                     boundingRect.size = e.mousePosition - boundingRect.min;
                     EditorGUI.DrawRect( boundingRect, Color.red );
                     Debug.Log( "Dragging continues "+boundingRect );
                 }
                 if( e.type == EventType.MouseUp )
                 {
                     e.Use();
                     Debug.Log( "Dragging stopped" );
                     boundingRect.min = Vector2.zero;
                 }
                 else if( e.type == EventType.MouseDown )
                 {
                     e.Use();
                     boundingRect.min = e.mousePosition;
                     boundingRect.size = Vector2.zero;
                     Debug.Log( "Dragging started" );
                 }
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to my problem, not an answer to my question, but instead of EditorGUI.DrawRect I used Handles. There might be something wrong with this solution, but it works. Here's that part as it stands now:

```
if( boundingRect.min != Vector2.zero && e.type == EventType.Repaint )
{
    boundingRect.size = e.mousePosition - boundingRect.min;
    Ray ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay( boundingRect.min );
    Vector3 posA = ray.origin + ray.direction;
    ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay( boundingRect.min + (boundingRect.width*Vector2.right) );
    Vector3 posB = ray.origin + ray.direction;
    ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay( boundingRect.max );
    Vector3 posC = ray.origin + ray.direction;
    ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay( boundingRect.min + (boundingRect.height*Vector2.up) );
    Vector3 posD = ray.origin + ray.direction;
    Handles.DrawDottedLine( posA, posB, 5 );
    Handles.DrawDottedLine( posB, posC, 5 );
    Handles.DrawDottedLine( posC, posD, 5 );
    Handles.DrawDottedLine( posD, posA, 5 );
    Debug.Log( "Dragging continues "+boundingRect );
}
```